# Video formats for websites: What are current best practices?

Tags: video, web, format

I am building a website that has many figures in video format. As I am just an amateur web developer, I have tried to search for information about video formats for websites but I am not sure if the information I got represents current (2014) best practices or not, hence my question. If that question is too vague or too broad, I would like to ask the following sub-questions:

1. Are there currently universal best practices in terms of what video formats to use for websites (as of March 2014)? If there are, what are those formats? If there are not, what top three video formats would you recommend?
2. If I have to choose only one video format, which one would you recommend for the widest browser support? (From what I have learned, it is either MP4 or Flash, but I am not sure which one or if the answer is one of them.)

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I highly recommend this blog post from Zencoder. It covers everything you are asking. http://blog.zencoder.com/2013/09/13/what-formats-do-i-need-for-html5-video/

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers nowadays support h264 encoded mp4 (internet explorer, Firefox, chrome, safari including their mobile versions). But if you want to offer compatibility options for older versions you have to use 3 formats mp4, webm and ogv.

Comment: Firefox does not support h.264. For Firefox vp8/9 is your best bet

Comment: I have ff27 and h264 mp4 files play fine. Try this: http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/peekintoo/peeks/8337996a8f08c2a7f8404a71ce0272895675c792.mp4

Comment: It can however use your operating systems built in media player which may or may not support h264. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @szatmary http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: @gtsouk: I have tried the link that you gave but it did not seem to work with Opera and Firefox for Mac (even version 27). Also, there are so many options for the H.264 format in the video format conversion software that I use (HandBrake), and I am not sure which is the most advisable to use. I tried some options for the same browsers (like Firefox), and they work with one version but not with another. That was why I was confused and asked for help here. Anyway, as you said, I have learned that H.264 is very widely supported. Many thanks for your advice.

Comment: @user3424398 If the video file i posted doesn't work then I guess ff for mac doesn't support mp4 yet. Try having all 3 formats (mp4,webm,ogv) if you want 100% compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not think there's any standard in the use of video formats, the most used are flv and mp4.

Today the vast majority of users have a good bandwidth, but at least for me it would be best to use the MP4 format, I feel It have very good quality and is a very lightweight format.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Actually I am a little more concerned with browser support/compatibility than with bandwidth issues.